# Js and bootstrap are not working when the file is in folder. Laravel

Tags: laravel

When i am including the file head.blade.php in views.home, JS and Bootstrap are working properly. But when i am trying to include head.blade.php in views.posts.create JS and bootstrap are not working. I found in previous questions  that i shoult include them like that:
   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="rel="stylesheet" {{URL::asset('css/responsive.css')}}">` but didn't helped.

This are my routes:

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/367SB.jpg)

[How should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxJmg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `/` to the front of your url:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Note: folder path should be **"project/public/css/"**

This can also be done with the `url()` helper function:

```
<link href="{{ url('/css/responsive.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Take a look at the [Laravel URL helper functions documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#urls) for more information.